# How to use keystone API extenstion to send a JSON format request "add global role to user "?

Tags: java, json, api, openstack, keystone

I want to use java to send a JSON format request to add an Admin role for openstack users, I see there is an keystone API extension that provide the `"add global role to user"` API:

This is the link :  [2.1.1.5. Add Global roles to a user.](http://docs.rackspace.com/openstack-extensions/auth/OS-KSADM-admin-devguide/content/PUT_addUserRole_v2.0_users__userId__roles_OS-KSADM__roleId__Admin_API_Service_Developer_Operations-d1e1357.html)

but I do not know how to send this in a correct way by JSON format, the following is my code:
I can get `"key_admin_url"` in another method,it is like: `130.237.215.18:35357/v2.0` and there is http before 130.

user_id and role_id are two strings.

```
     //create connection
    public static void addRole(){
    try{
    URL url = new URL(key_admin_url + "/users/" + "user_id" + "/roles/OS-KSADM/" + "role_id");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token",
                "012345SECRET99TOKEN012345");
        connection.connect();
        //put request 
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());
                  out.flush();
                 out.close();
      //read response
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String lines;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        while ((lines = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines = new String(lines.getBytes(), "utf-8");
            sb.append(lines);
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
        reader.close();
        // disconnect
        connection.disconnect();
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

But I did not succeed and get :java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL:

Is there anyone know how to send a correct JSON request to add role to users? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved, because in URI, there is no tenant_id. So the correct URI is

```
URL url = new URL(key_admin_url + "/tenants/" + "tenant_id" + "/users/" + "user_id" + "/roles/OS-KSADM/" + "role_id");
```